# How to join tables when left join does not generate null values for the dates

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have three tables as shown below:

**1. kit_test tk**

```
tk.id  tk.first_name  tk.last_name  tk.dob     tk.registered_dt
SD007  Aarushi        Sharma        2/23/1987  10/5/2020
SD008  Camden         Howard        8/22/1993  10/6/2020
```

**2. employee_badged emp**

```
emp.firstname   emp.lastname    emp.ssno    emp.empid
 Aarushi        Sharma          5175        570
 Camden         Howard          23513       804
```

**3. event_badged events**

```
events.empid    events.event_time_utc
   570              10/5/2020
   570              10/6/2020
   570              10/7/2020
   570              10/8/2020
   804              10/15/2020
   804              10/16/2020
```

This is my desired Output.

```
regname     firstname    lastname   registered_date enterdate      count
Aarushi Sharma  Aarushi Sharma   10/5/2020      10/5/2020         1
Aarushi Sharma  Aarushi Sharma   10/5/2020      10/6/2020         1
Aarushi Sharma  Aarushi Sharma   10/5/2020      10/7/2020         1
Aarushi Sharma  Aarushi Sharma   10/5/2020      10/8/2020         1
Aarushi Sharma  Aarushi Sharma   10/5/2020      10/9/2020   
Aarushi Sharma  Aarushi Sharma   10/5/2020      10/10/2020  
Camden Howard   Camden  Howard   10/6/2020
```

This is the query I have so far:

```
select distinct tk.first_name + ' ' + tk.last_name as "regname", EMP.FIRSTNAME, EMP.LASTNAME,
    trunc(tk.registered_dt) as registered_date,
    trunc(EVENTS.EVENT_TIME_UTC) as enterdate
    
    FROM kit_test as tk
    left join employee_badged emp
    ON tk.first_name + ' ' + tk.last_name=emp.FIRSTNAME + ' ' + emp.LASTNAME
    
    left join event_badged events
    ON EVENTS.EMPID=EMP.ID
    
    where
    date(tk.registered_dt) between '2020-10-05' and '2020-10-10'
    and (trunc(EVENTS.EVENT_TIME_UTC)  between '2020-10-05' and '2020-10-10') ;
```

I am performing this task on RedShift/Dbeaver/PostgreSQL.

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as formatted text, not as images.

Comment: This sounds like you've already had some draft SQL query, why won't you share it?

Comment: Can you please look into this now, @jarlh

Comment: Can you please look into this now, @AlexLarionov

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you should FIRST left join the 2 events tables, THEN left join the tested employees with the subquery of results.

something like this (i can't test it so maybe some correction coul be done on this query)

```
select distinct tk.first_name + ' ' + tk.last_name as "regname", emp_events.FIRSTNAME, emp_events.LASTNAME,
trunc(tk.registered_dt) as registered_date,
trunc(emp_events.EVENT_TIME_UTC) as enterdate

FROM kit_test as tk
left join (

   select emp_badges.firstname, emp_badges.lastname events.event_time_utc
   from  employee_badged emp_badges
   left join event_badged events
   ON EMP_badges.ID=EVENTS.EMPID
   where
    (trunc(EVENTS.EVENT_TIME_UTC)  between '2020-10-05' and '2020-10-10') 
) emp_events

ON tk.first_name + ' ' + tk.last_name=emp_events.FIRSTNAME + ' ' + emp_events.LASTNAME
where
date(tk.registered_dt) between '2020-10-05' and '2020-10-10';
```

Maybe you can't do it, but adding the employee_id in the kit_test table would be improving a lot the table and query design